# The difference between ticks & fleas?

Tags: insect-bites, fleas

My mother went to a campsite near a lake and came back with **reddish-brown dots** all over her pant legs.

She's not sure whether they are ticks or fleas.  Her pants sat in her room for two days before she realized.

I browsed the internet, saw several people said fleas are reddish-brown so thought that was it, but then found a few posts where people said ticks are also reddish-brown.  So now we're right where we started - nowhere.

I told her to see a small-animal veterinarian because they would likely be knowledgeable about ticks & fleas.  In the meantime (they're closed today):

- Q: **Are they ticks or fleas?**
- Q: Do both the vehicle and house need to be treated?  If so, what product is recommended?

Since she has been bitten:

- Q: Does she need to be treated with anything?

Comment: Tick are arachnids, fleas are insects. The former has eight legs, the latter, six. I would think the color of either would depend on the species in question.

Comment: Bill is correct.  Also she should do a full self skin exam and look for any attached ticks, and remove them according to https://www.cdc.gov/ticks/removing_a_tick.html  and since it's been more than 2 days, she should see a doctor if she finds anything unusual.

Comment: Neither ticks nor fleas would remain immobile on her pants, so if those dots have been there for two days the answer is neither. I don't think this question can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

@Carey Gregory: You're right, they are neither.

She went to a small-animal vet clinic as I suggested and had them looked at under a microscope; the vet confirmed **they are neither ticks nor fleas** and didn't have an idea as to what they might be.  **They had 6 legs.**

Needless to say, she is relieved but still curious.